# Numbering an equation when using \displaymath

Tags: math-mode, labels

I am using the `hyperref` package and want to label a piecewise equation.  However, I only know how to use `\displaymath` to do a piecewise equation and the `\label` doesn't put a number next to the equation.  Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,hyperref}



\begin{document}


\begin{displaymath} \label{eq:torus}
   A_{T(p,q)}(z,w)  = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       w(w+2qz - \frac{1}{2}) & : p =2, q>2 \\
\\
       w(w + pqz - \frac{1}{2})(w+pqz) & : p,q > 2 
     \end{array}
   \right.
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `hyperref` package does not provide the number to equations, only links to it. Do you use a `\label` command in the equation at all?

Comment: `\displaystyle` does not provide numbers itself

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer I labelled the \begin{displaymath} but it does not put a number

Comment: Is there a way to do piecewise function with \begin{equation}?  Then it will be numbered.

Comment: See my answer please -- use the `cases` environment for such piecewise functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `displaymath` environment does not provide an equation number:

```
\begin{displaymath} \label{somelabel}
```

will use the last counter being used in the `\refstepcounter` call and this is certainly not what is wanted here.

To get the labels it is necessary to use a numbering math environment, e.g. `equation` or `align` and then use the `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` environment for the specific setup of a piecewise function.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,hyperref}

\begin{document}


%\begin{displaymath}  \label{eq:torus}
%
%A_{T(p,q)}(z,w) = \left\{
%     \begin{array}{ll}
%       w(w+2qz - \frac{1}{2}) & : p =2, q>2 \\
%\\
%       w(w + pqz - \frac{1}{2})(w+pqz) & : p,q > 2 
%     \end{array}
%   \right.
%
%\end{displaymath}


\begin{equation}
  A_{T(p,q)}(z,w) = \begin{cases}
    w(w+2qz - \frac{1}{2}) & : p =2, q>2 \\
    w(w + pqz - \frac{1}{2})(w+pqz) & : p,q > 2  
  \end{cases} \label{eq:torus}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output equation]

Comment: Thank you, I will not be using \displaymath ever again.  And thank you for the extra clarification of what environments give numbering.

Comment: @ndruiven: You can use `\displaymath` for nice inline math, but it is not designed to provide equation numbers